# MKLaunchOptionsCameraKey in 'openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:' not accepting MKCameraItem* as valid property list format

Tags: ios, mapkit, property-list, mkmapcamera

I am attempting to open the Maps app upon tapping on an annotation callout accessory, which works fine, except when I pass a dictionary containing a `MKMapCamera*` as value for `MKLaunchOptionsCameraKey`. (This is to open Maps with a 3D scene loaded)

This is how it should work according to the docs; is this a bug or am I missing something? Do I need to serialize the camera object into an `NSData` object?

NSLog tells me :

> Property List invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain
>   objects of type 'CFType')

```
MKMapCamera* camera = [MKCamera cameraLookingAtCenterCoordinate: [view.annotation coordinate] 
                                              fromEyeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake ([view.annotation coordinate].latitude + .01 , [view.annotation coordinate].longitude + .01 )
                                                    eyeAltitude:10]; 
 NSDictionary* options = @{MKLaunchOptionsCameraKey : camera};
 [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:options];
```

Like I said, it works fine if the dictionary is say:

```
 NSDictionary* options = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchDirectionsModeDriving }; 
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:options];
```

I thought Objective-C objects were valid property-list (and Dictionary) entries, so what gives?
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edits, guys! Reading up on how to do stuff like that for future questions